# Transfer data withou buffer from MultipartMemoryStreamProvider to an output stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, upload, proxy

I am doing kind of a proxy. A client uploads file to Web API method, this web API method sends file to some other HTTP location. I have this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task mPost(string id)
{     
    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    var r = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(async t =>
    {
        var file = provider.Contents.First();                
        var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

            using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
            {                       
                using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "target_url"))
                {        
                    req.Content = content;

                    using (HttpResponseMessage resp = client.SendAsync(req).Result)
                    {
                        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

It works, but what i don't like is that at some point (`var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`) I have all file data in server's memory.

How to transfer data directly from input stream to output without keeping it in memory buffer?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?